# Jquery star rating mashing all the stars together

Tags: php, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am using the jquery ui widget star rating. After my query echos then all of the stars are shown together (and also the wrong amount if there are more than 2 reviews in the query but everything is correct if there is only 1 review in the query).

Here is the code:

this function assigns the number 1 at the start to an array to know which stars are filled.

```
  function get_stars ($rating) {
    if( $rating == 0 ) $rating = 1;
    $ratings_array = array_fill (1, 5, 0);
    for ($index=(int)$rating; $index>0; $index--) {
      $ratings_array[$index] = 1;
    }
    return $ratings_array;
  }
```

the query I echoed and tried directly in phpmyadmin to make sure it works:

```
select r.reviews_id, rd.reviews_text, r.reviews_rating, r.date_added, r.customers_name from reviews r join reviews_description rd on rd.reviews_id = r.reviews_id where r.products_id = '40' and rd.languages_id = '1' and reviews_status = '1' order by r.reviews_id DESC
```

which outputs 2 rows. 5 columns just like it is supposed to: 
reviews_id
reviews_text
reviews_rating
date_added
customers_name

Here is the full while loop with the query, and the table that is echoed:

```
                <table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tbody>
<?php
    if (SPECIFICATIONS_MAX_REVIEWS > '0') {
      $reviews_count_query_raw = "
        select
          count(*) as count
        from
          " . TABLE_REVIEWS . "
        where
          products_id = '" . (int) $_GET['products_id'] . "'
          and reviews_status = '1'
      ";
      // print 'Count Query: ' . $reviews_count_query_raw . '<br>';
      $reviews_count_query = tep_db_query ($reviews_count_query_raw);
      $reviews = tep_db_fetch_array ($reviews_count_query);

      $reviews_query_average_raw = "
        select
          (avg(reviews_rating)) as average_rating
        from
          " . TABLE_REVIEWS . "
        where
          products_id = '" . (int) $_GET['products_id'] . "'
          and reviews_status = '1'
      ";
      // print 'Average Query: ' . $reviews_query_average_raw . '<br>';
      $reviews_query_average = tep_db_query ($reviews_query_average_raw);
      $reviews_average = tep_db_fetch_array ($reviews_query_average);
      $reviews_stars = $reviews_average['average_rating'];

      $reviews_query_raw = "
        select
          r.reviews_id,
          rd.reviews_text,
          r.reviews_rating,
          r.date_added,
          r.customers_name
        from
          " . TABLE_REVIEWS . " r
          join " . TABLE_REVIEWS_DESCRIPTION . " rd
            on rd.reviews_id = r.reviews_id
        where r.products_id = '" . (int) $_GET['products_id'] . "'
          and rd.languages_id = '" . $languages_id . "'
          and reviews_status = '1'
        order by r.reviews_id DESC
      ";
      // print $reviews_query_raw . '<br>';
      $reviews_query = tep_db_query( $reviews_query_raw );
      $num_rows = tep_db_num_rows( $reviews_query );
    echo $reviews_query_raw;
      if ($num_rows > 0) {
        $row = 0;
        while ($reviews = tep_db_fetch_array ($reviews_query)) {
          if ($row < SPECIFICATIONS_MAX_REVIEWS) {
            $row++;
            $date_added = tep_date_short ($reviews['date_added']);
// Show product reviews
?>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="main">

<?php 

                    $rating = get_stars($reviews['reviews_rating']);
                    echo  tep_draw_radio_field ('rating', '1', $rating[1], 'class="star" disabled="disabled"') .
                    ' ' . tep_draw_radio_field ('rating', '2', $rating[2], 'class="star" disabled="disabled"') .
                    ' ' . tep_draw_radio_field ('rating', '3', $rating[3], 'class="star" disabled="disabled"') .
                    ' ' . tep_draw_radio_field ('rating', '4', $rating[4], 'class="star" disabled="disabled"') .
                    ' ' . tep_draw_radio_field ('rating', '5', $rating[5], 'class="star" disabled="disabled"') .
                      sprintf (TEXT_REVIEW_BY, tep_output_string_protected ($reviews['customers_name']) ) .  ', ' .
                          tep_date_long ($reviews['date_added']);

?>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td valign="top" class="main">
<?php
            echo tep_break_string (tep_output_string_protected ($reviews['reviews_text']), 60, '<br>') . ( (strlen ($reviews['reviews_text']) >= 100) ? '<br>' : '') .
                                   '... &nbsp; &nbsp;' .
                                   '<a href="' . tep_href_link (FILENAME_PRODUCT_REVIEWS_INFO, 'products_id=' . $product_info['products_id'] . '&reviews_id=' . $reviews['reviews_id']) . '">' .
                                   'Read Full Review</a>';
?>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
<?php
           } // if ($row
         } // while ($reviews
?>
                      <tr>
                        <td><?php echo tep_draw_separator ('pixel_trans.gif', '100%', '10'); ?></td>
                      </tr>
<?php
       } // if ($num_rows
     } // if (SPECIFICATIONS_MAX_REVIEWS

?>
                      <tr>
                        <td><?php echo tep_draw_separator ('pixel_trans.gif', '100%', '10'); ?></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
<?php
```

the end result looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoiJs.png

note that one review is 5 stars and the other is 2 stars. So it is not even the correct amount of starts, but also merging them together.

However if I only have 1 review active in this case the 2 star it works perfectly:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu7sI.png

This is the widget: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/

Comment: What does the column `reviews_rating` contain for each of these examples?

Comment: Reason I ask is because I feel you are over thinking this!

Comment: The number, of starts 1-5 so in this case it was 2 and 4.  I just figured out the provlem. The tep_draw_radio_field function was outputting the same name of the radio field. so I just added $row to the name and now it works perfectly